# Unable to install `gattlib`

Tags: python, installation, package, apt, gattlib

I am trying to install [`gattlib`](https://pypi.org/project/gattlib/) in Python in order to use some of its Bluetooth-tools.

The OS is ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I have by now tried the following (as e.g. [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55530/pybluez-and-gattlib-error)):

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib
cd pygattlib
cat DEPENDS
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev libboost-python-dev    libbluetooth-dev libglib2.0-dev python-dev
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

which gives (my Python is 3.6.9):

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-python36
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Also, I tried:

```
sudo apt install python3-gattlib
```

which gives:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-gattlib: Depends: python3 (>= 3.7~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
                 Depends: libboost-python1.67.0 but is is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-thread1.67.0 but is is not installable
```

despite libboost-python and libboost-thread being successfully installed in the first attempt (see above), and `python3` returning `Python 3.6.9`.

```
pip3 install gattlib
```

shows:

```
Building wheel for gattlib(setup.py) ... error

Running setup.py install for gattlib ... error
```

Which is the exact same result that I get from [(following instructions from this question):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463847/got-error-while-download-gattlib-via-pip3/52271293#52271293)

```
sudo pip3 download gattlib  
sudo tar xvzf ./gattlib-0.20200122.tar.gz
cd gattlib-0.20200122/
sudo sed -ie 's/boost_python-py34/boost_python36/' setup.py
pip3 install .
```

in which I understand to be a necessary adjustment of the installation file before running it, because, if I understood correctly, the python version is somehow wrongly hardcoded in there.

Futher things I tried and that did not help:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo pip3 install gattlib
wget -qO- http://pike.esi.uclm.es/add-pike-repo.sh | sudo sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-gattlib
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo apt-get install mercurial
pip3 install gattlib
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

cd /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libboost_python-py35.so libboost_python-py36.so

sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev bluez bluez-hcidump libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libglib2.0-dev

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib
cd pygattlib
cat DEPENDS
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev libboost-python-dev    libbluetooth-dev libglib2.0-dev python-dev
sudo python3 setup.py install
sudo python setup.py install

pip3 install gTTS

sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev \
build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
python-pip
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: error with `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++` can means you have to install compiler C/C++ - probably `apt install gcc`

Comment: dependencies shows that you have to use Python 3.7 and you need `libboost-python` and `libboost-thread` version `1.67.0` but it is avaliable in Ubuntu 19.04 - see [libboost-thread1.67.0_1.67.0-13_amd64.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libboost-thread1.67.0_1.67.0-13_amd64.deb.html). I have Linux Mint 19.3 based on Ubuntu 18.04 and can't install `1.67` because it makes conflict with already installed `1.65`

Comment: Do you mean these are only available on Ubuntu 19.04? I know for a fact that I had actually managed to install `gattlib´ on Ubuntu 18.04 before. `sudo apt-get install libboost-1.67.0` does not work for me, though (unable to locate package). `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` returns "already newest version (1.65.1.0ubuntu1).

Comment: I have the same on Linux Mint (also based on Ubuntu 18.04). I can't find `libboost-1.67.0` with `apt`. When I download it and try to install manually then it shows message about conflict with older version `1.65` so I don't try to replace it. I edited `setup.py` and this way I resolved problem with `libboost-python` because `setup` tried to use `libboost-python37` but I have `libboost-python3-py36`  (I found it using `locate libboost-python`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

and I also get error

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-python36
```

because I don't have `boost-python36.a` but `boost-python3-py36.a`.

(I found this file using `locate boost-python3` which uses database with filenames so it works faster then `find` but it may not be installed as default)

I had to edit `setup.py` and change

```
boost_libs = ["boost_python3"+str(sys.version_info.minor)]
```

to

```
boost_libs = ["boost_python3-py36"]
```

or more universal

```
boost_libs = ["boost_python3-py3"+str(sys.version_info.minor)]
```

---

Tested od Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia based on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `python-dev` that contains the header files for the Python C API. The following should do the trick (make sure to replace `X` with your Python version):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.X-dev
```

Comment: While this downloaded 744MB of stuff, the errors when attempting to install my code, just as I tried before, are unchanged.

Comment: @Marie.P. What Python version are you running?

Comment: @Marie.P. have you also tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential `?

Comment: I tried the `build-essential`, and it is already at the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
Python is 2.7.17, and python3 is 3.6.9

Comment: @Marie.P. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I thought that 2.7.17 and 3.6.9, respectively, are the answers to this question? What information shall I provide?

Comment: These are the python version you have __installed__ on your machine. You can't use both of them at the same time.

Comment: I am primarily trying to run `gattlib`  in Python 3, although compatibility with `Python 2` would be a plus.

Comment: Yes, but I am not convinced that you actually know which version you are currently running.

Comment: @Marie.P. check `pip3 -V` and `python3 -V` - if you want to install for `Python 2` then check `pip -V` or `pip2 -V` and `python -V` or `python2 -V`

Comment: `pip3 -V` and `pip -V` both return `pip 20.0.2 (python 3.6)`

Answer (score 0):

With ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ wget https://github.com/oscaracena/pygattlib/releases/download/v.20201113/python3-gattlib_0.20201113-1_amd64.deb

$ sudo apt install ./python3-gattlib*.deb

$ pip3 install gattlib
```

Reference:
https://pypi.org/project/gattlib/

NOTE: This didn't work for me!

```
sudo apt install pkg-config libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libbluetooth-dev libglib2.0-dev python-dev
```